# React Native - Fetch is not a function. Fetch is undefined

Tags: react-native, fetch

I am having a very odd issue recently with one of my project, in one of my page I use a fetch in order to get a file from internet and use the result. But for some reason on both ios and android if I am in debug mode it works but if I leave the debug it gives me a crash.

Debug :

[image: Activate debug]
[image: Stop debug]

I was using react-native 0.53.0 so I tried upgrading to 0.53.3 and now 0.54.4 and it gives me the same result.

```
 fetch('http://www.podcast411.com/new_demo_feed.xml')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then((response) => {
      console.log("Parsing", response)
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('fetch', err)
  })
```

For configuration I use :

```
"npm": "^5.8.0",
"react": "^16.3.0-alpha.1",
"react-native": "0.54.4",
...(lots more librairies)...
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.2.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.2.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
  },
```

Thanks for your help

[image: IOS Error]

Comment: What do you mean by leave the debug mode?

Comment: @VishalJadav I mean activate the debug mode or not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was found by my colleague the problem was that in some part of my code I was assigning this to a var

`var self = this`

and not releasing it which seems to make (even in another view) the normally available `this.fetch` unavailable.

So after removing all the assignation the bug is gone... 
Hope it will help some of you too